# audio from different user (su) on xubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, user-management

I am using firefox on a different user, for example with:

```
LANG=C xhost +SI:localuser:${1}
su ${1}
```

or

```
xhost +SI:localuser:$1
sudo -u $1 -H /usr/bin/firefox -P
```

Since the upgrade from 18.04 to xubuntu 20.04, I have no audio on the firefox-user, but this user is still part of the audio group.
In the *PulseAudio Preferences*, one setting must be activated. I guess it was "*Network Server*" "*Enable network access to local sound devices*...", but this option is grayed out.

---

**What I could find out:**

---

The options are greyed out at 20.04 because of a bug, workaround:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/pulse-13.99.1 /usr/lib/pulse-13.99
```

https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/gvtzpb/ubuntu_2004_lts_x86_64_trying_to_use_paprefs_but/

---

Here is an example from MetaEatMe:
[SUDO and sound, how to make them work together](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182238/sudo-and-sound-how-to-make-them-work-together)

"Enable network access to local sound devices" was sufficient at 18.04, but at 20.04 I still have no sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found something that is working on focal (20.04):

```
# setup user audio permission
usermod -aG audio suUser

# add to config /etc/pulse/client.conf
auto-connect-localhost = yes

# add to config /etc/pulse/default.pa
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp listen=127.0.0.1 auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1 auth-anonymous=1
```

The original solution was here:
https://superuser.com/a/1499880

Thanks to user keypress